# Class set to time out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a pop up to show onMouseOver which I can do below. But how can I then remove the class onMouseOut?

```
// Get the snackbar DIV
var x = document.getElementById("snackbar2")

// Add the "show" class to DIV
x.className = "show";
```

Comment: `x.className = ""`. You are better off using classList

Answer (score 0):

To add a class:

```
x.classList.add('show');
```

To remove a class:

```
x.classList.remove('show');
```

To toggle a class on and off:

```
x.classList.toggle('show');
```

To check if an element has a class or not:

```
if (x.classList.contains('show'))
```

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)